# Speech bubble inside repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

[image]

Above is an image of the rendered css when I changed the bg color of .speech_bubble_content to red. The bubble isn't displaying properly.

I am using the following code to retrieve data from a database and bind it to a repeater. I am also using css to display a speech bubble around what I want to display. I noticed that data is displayed when I place a label outisde of the div - and nothing is retrieved when the label is inside the div - in this case creation date is displayed, but story is omitted. Why is this happening? Thanks for your help. I believe this is caused by css.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">

   <ItemTemplate>

    <div class="speech_bubble">
    <b class="sb1"></b><b class="sb2"></b><b class="sb3"></b><b class="sb4"></b><b class="sb5"></b><b class="sb6"></b><b class="sb7"></b>
    <div class="speech_bubble_content">
    <p>

    <asp:Label ID="story" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Story") %>'></asp:Label>


    </p>

    </div>
    <b class="sb7"></b><b class="sb6"></b><b class="sb5"></b><b class="sb4"></b><b class="sb3"></b><b class="sb2"></b><b class="sb1"></b>
    <em></em><span></span>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="user" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CompanyRole") %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="date" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CreationDate") %>'></asp:Label>

    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.speech_bubble{
background: transparent;
margin:10px 0;
}
.speech_bubble_content{
display:block; 
background:#fff; 
border:3px solid #ddd; 
border-width:0 3px;
}
.speech_bubble p{
padding:0.5em 0; 
color:#000;
margin:0 15px; 
}
.sb1, .sb2, .sb3, .sb4, .sb5, .sb6, .sb7{
display:block; 
overflow:hidden; 
font-size:0;
}
.sb1, .sb2, .sb3, .sb4, .sb5, .sb6{
height:1px;
}
.sb4, .sb5, .sb6, .sb7{
background:#fff; 
border-left:1px solid #ddd; 
border-right:1px solid #ddd;
}
.sb1 {margin:0 8px; background:#ddd;}
.sb2 {margin:0 6px; background:#ddd;}
.sb3 {margin:0 4px; background:#ddd;}
.sb4 {margin:0 3px; background:#fff; border-width:0 5px;}
.sb5 {margin:0 2px; background:#fff; border-width:0 4px;}
.sb6 {margin:0 2px; background:#fff; border-width:0 3px;} 
.sb7 {margin:0 1px; background:#fff; border-width:0 3px; height:2px;} 

.speech_bubble em{
display:block; 
width:0; 
height:0; 
overflow:hidden; 
border-top:12px solid #ddd; 
border-left:12px dotted transparent; 
border-right:12px dotted transparent; 
margin-left:50px;
}
.speech_bubble span{
display:block; 
width:0; 
height:0; 
overflow:hidden; 
border-top:10px solid #fff; 
border-left:10px dotted transparent; 
border-right:10px dotted transparent; 
margin-left:52px; 
margin-top:-15px;
}
```

Comment: Is the problem that the story text is not in the html at all (check with view source) or that the css style prevent that it is showing? In the latter case you need to provide the relevant styles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes do as rene suggest. View the source, HTML copy it and the CSS and save it to http://jsbin.com/  and send the Link back here so we can see the REAL html that .NET generates.

You might also just want to have

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Story") %>
```

instead of using a asp:label as it will add unwanted HTML tags.